# Machine/@currentSnapshot attribute is missing

Tags: virtualbox

I am working on building some application for linux on a debian distro of linux on a virtualbox.  Everything was going great.  I turned off my virtualbox and when I start it back up, I get this error and now I cannot even access the os.

```
Error in /home/****/VirtualBox VMs/Debian/Debian.vbox (line 9) -- 
Snapshots present but required Machine/@currentSnapshot attribute is 
missing.

/build/virtualbox-mnp3zF/virtualbox-5.0.32-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-
server/MachineImpl.cpp[480] (nsresult Machine::initFromSettings(VirtualBox*, 
const com::Utf8Str&, const com::Guid*)).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) 
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}
Callee: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following attribute to the line 9 of your vbox file:
currentSnapshot="{xxx}", 
where xxx should correspond to snapshot uuid (it's a tag within the same file)
hope this works for you...

Comment: I ended up just deleting it.  I did try that,  but it did not work.  Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: This fix worked for me, but to clarify the answer a little, you get the {xxx} value for currentSnapshot from the <Snapshots> tag, thus:

<Snapshots>
                                                            <Snapshot uuid="{xxx}" ...

Answer (score 2):

confirmed, this just happened to me with Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.20 r114628 (Qt5.6.2) ..... **and your fix saved all my guest os configuration work of several weeks!!!!** thank you so much, Lyoncha!

### **broken:**

```
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.16-windows">
  <Machine uuid="{d82345e-849b-435402-adgbc-a3210d234d7}" name="MyGuest3" OSType="Ubuntu_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" currentStateModified="false" lastStateChange="2017-04-21T17:19:05Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
```

---

### **fixed:**

```
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.16-windows">
  <Machine currentSnapshot="{2345623asdf45sdg}" uuid="{d82345e-849b-435402-adgbc-a3210d234d7}" name="MyGuest3" OSType="Ubuntu_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" currentStateModified="false" lastStateChange="2017-04-21T17:19:05Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
```

---

Comment: Where did you find the value `2345623asdf45sdg`?  I don't see anything that looks similar in my .vbox file, but then again there is a lot of stuff  there. @Lynocha 's post seems to imply that a uuid goes there but those seem like substantially longer strings that contain hyphens.